# Background color of RoundedImageView turns to Black automatically

Tags: java, android, android-studio, bitmap, base64

> I am trying to display a **transparent image (bitmap) using setImageBitmap() in a RoundedImageView** with background color as blue within a BottomSheetDialog. **Without the bitmap the background color is blue** but as soon as the **bitmap is loaded into the view the blue background changes to black**. I tried using setBackgroundColor("blue") but the background of the RoundedImageView still remains black and also shows a blue square background with my RoundedImageView, which is definitely not intended.

**The RoundedImageView Element**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/bottomSheetContainer"
    android:background="@drawable/background_bottomsheet">

<com.makeramen.roundedimageview.RoundedImageView
    android:id="@+id/bottomSheetPhoto"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/_80sdp"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/_80sdp"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_16sdp"
    android:background="@drawable/image_background"
    app:riv_border_width="@dimen/_2sdp"
    app:riv_border_color="@color/white"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    app:riv_mutate_background="true"
    android:forceDarkAllowed="false"
    app:riv_oval="true" />
```

**image_background.xml**

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:shape="oval">
   <solid android:color="@color/bright_blue"/>

</shape>
```

**Code for encoding image**

```
private String encodeImage(Bitmap bitmap)
{
    int previewWidth = 150;
    int previewHeight = bitmap.getHeight() * previewWidth / bitmap.getWidth();
    Bitmap previewBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, previewWidth,previewHeight,false);
    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    previewBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,50,byteArrayOutputStream);
    byte[] bytes = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
    return Base64.encodeToString(bytes,Base64.DEFAULT);
}
```

Comment: try glide transformation and imageView (https://github.com/wasabeef/glide-transformations) instrad com.makeramen.roundedimageview.RoundedImageView

Comment: @amir.ashrafi I actually got the required background and image using RoundedImageView previously and it worked. But I am not able to get that here, so I need to know what went wrong with RoundedImageView here.

Comment: the problem is somewhere else .it seems getting image bitmap in the wrong way .
maybe when image turned to bitmap or get image from source
check the image before set it to imageview
setImageBitmap function sets image as a source and if your image is a transparent it must work successful

Comment: @amir.ashrafi Yes, you are right! Actually I used base 64 to encode the image but in JPEG format. I have found out that JPEG cannot be transparent. I changed it to PNG and it works perfectly fine now! Thankyou so much for your guidance :)

Comment: your welcome and you can vote my comments for others